# ASP.Net Core web application drawing objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

We're having a requirement to build an OS independent application where we need to draw Rectangles, Lines and Ellipse.

We are developing in a ASP.Net Core (MVC) application to realize the OS independence.

Our ideal situation is to prefix the drawing objects in a model class (height, width, color) and request the objects in the controller or razor view to show them on the web page.

We've searched on the internet and found several options with a BitMap of System.Drawing.Common.
The most common solution is a form application witch we want to avoid, because it isn't OS independent.

What is the best suggestion to realize our situation?
We are not afraid to try the combination of C#, JS HTML and so one, only requirement it needs to fit in the ASP.Net Core application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at fabric.js for interacting with the html canvas.

You can develop directly with the canvas, but it will be much easier to use a library that already handles all the heavy lifting.

see: http://fabricjs.com

Answer (score 0):

What about `<canvas>` ?

The HTML `<canvas>` element is used to draw graphics on a web page.

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvOK=1;
try {c.getContext("2d");}
catch (er) {canvOK=0;}
if (canvOK==1)
 {
 var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
 ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,50);
 
 var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(140,20,240,70);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"white");
    ctx.fillStyle=grd;
    ctx.fillRect(140,20,100,50);
    
    var grd2=ctx.createLinearGradient(20,90,120,90);
    grd2.addColorStop(0,"black");
    grd2.addColorStop("0.3","magenta");
    grd2.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
    grd2.addColorStop("0.6","green");
    grd2.addColorStop("0.8","yellow");
    grd2.addColorStop(1,"red");
    ctx.fillStyle=grd2;
    ctx.fillRect(20,90,100,50);
    
    ctx.font="30px Verdana";
    var grd3=ctx.createLinearGradient(140,20,240,90);
    grd3.addColorStop(0,"black");
    grd3.addColorStop("0.3","magenta");
    grd3.addColorStop("0.6","blue");
    grd3.addColorStop("0.8","green");
    grd3.addColorStop(1,"red");
    ctx.strokeStyle=grd3;
    ctx.strokeText("Smile!",140,120); }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="270" height="160" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:15px">
Your browser does not support the &lt;canvas&gt; element.
</canvas>
```

The graphic to the above is created with ''. It shows four elements: a red rectangle, a gradient rectangle, a multicolor rectangle, and a multicolor text.

What is HTML Canvas?

The HTML `<canvas>` element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript.

The `<canvas>` element is only a container for graphics. You must use JavaScript to actually draw the graphics.

Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images.

for complete view

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=canvas

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve a similar objective in an asp.net core 2.0 project. From my ".cshtml" razor view, I am calling a Typescript routine to handle to GUI complexity. Within the view, I am using a HTML5 canvas on which I want to draw rectangles over a background image.

`[jsFiddle][1]` seems to be the best website to understanding the various interaction of these aspects (HTML, CSS, TypeScript), specifically these examples:

- [Creating circles with a mouse](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/nXmTC/)
- [Circle drawing in fabricjs](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/Nt8f7/)

Currently, I not 100% sure how to include "Fabric.js" within the project "wwwroot" directory (or other locations within the project) and secondly how to maintain the background image throughout the drawing of circles, lines etc.

This seems to align with all the responses above. I do know that "System.Drawing" are **not** available within ".NET Core 2.0" (even via a NuGet package), so unfortunately other methods need to be pursued.